# how to query from a literal list : select * from ('a', 'b', 'c')

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm using `mysql 5.5`, here is a left join query with a  `literal` list:

```
select tbl1.*, details.* 
from ('a', 'b', 'c'... 300+ elements) as 'tbl1' 
left join details
on 
details.id=tbl1.id
```

but it doesn't work!

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a','b')' at line 1`

how to make this `list` as a table??

Comment: what is 'a', 'b', 'c'... 300+ elements here

Comment: @PSR means this is a list with 300+ elements

Comment: create temp table and insert all elements, then as normal join you can get results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **UNION**

```
select tbl1.*, details.* 
from (select 'a'as id
      union
      select 'b' as id
      union
      select 'c' as id
      union
      ...300) as tbl1
left join details
on 
details.id=tbl1.id
```

See this **[Fiidle Logic](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11270)**

Instead of using **Subquery**, you can first create a table `tbl1` as

```
create table tbl1
(
id varchar(1)
)

insert into tbl1
select 'a' as id
union 
select 'b' as id
union 
select 'c' as id
....300
```

now you can use **table tbl1** for `join`

```
select tbl1.*, details.* 
from 'tbl1' 
left join details
on 
details.id=tbl1.id
```

Comment: `insert into tbl1(id) values ('a'),('b')...300+` can do the same, and more clear

Comment: @Kevin混合理论 If it solved your problem, try considering it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Missing a select in your sub-query ?

```
select tbl1.*, details.* 
    from (select 'a', 'b', 'c'... 300+ elements) as 'tbl1' 
    left join details
    on 
    details.id=tbl1.id
```

But I don't understand what your left join is supposed to do

[EDIT] Create a temp table for your join ?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable ( tempcol varchar(100) ) ENGINE=heap; 

insert into TempTable
values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), 300+ elements);

select TempTable.*, details.*
from TempTable
left join details on details.id = TempTable.tempcol;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select tbl1.*, details.* 
from (select 'a', 'b', 'c' as id) as tbl1
left join details
on 
details.id=tbl1.id
```

Comment: your Result :
a| b| id   \n 
a| b| c|

Comment: Could you pls include your raw data and expected result then? I am just merely corrected your syntax error. Not sure what is the result you want achive?